# How to path files in javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've this code in a fille called: general.js

```
if($('#showcase').length) {
$.include('js/jquery.aw-showcase.js');
```

}

But as we all know, Wordpress uses `bloginfo('template_url')` to path files.

In front-end not work because show incorrect path `<script type="text-javascript" src="js/jquery.aw-showcase.js"></script>`

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but you could always declare a JS variable early in your main index file, like such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var template_url = "<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>";
</script>
```

Now, in your general.js file, you can reference it as such:

```
if ($('#showcase').length) {
    $.include(template_url + '/js/jquery.aw-showcase.js');
}
```

You should usually avoid using a global variable, but it might be the only solution in this case.

EDIT:  You might actually want to use [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) instead of declaring a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

At least, could you not try this ?

```
if($('#showcase').length) {
  $.include('/wp-content/themes/yourthemename/js/jquery.aw-showcase.js');
}
```